# Parent variable in plugin gets overwritten

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm very new to making jQuery plugins and there is one problem i stumble upon every time. The plugin below is a simple plugin to embed a facebook likebox for a page or link to a user profile based on a username or facebook url. It works like a charm when it's executed once.

When executed multiple times only the last one gets filled with the $.ajax part. If i console.log($this) there al the last one.

It looks like the $this in the ajax call is overwritten... it also happens in other plugins when i use another each() in the plugin.

I hope i'm clear, i tried to put it in a jsFiddle but i get the error "Input plain JavaScript code, no HTML."

```
jQuery.fn.facebookEmbed = function( options ) {

var defaults = {
    likebox: "Loading facebook...",
    faces: false,
    stream: true,
    header: false,
    width: 252,
    customClass: 'facebookembed',
    account: "skrillex"
};  

var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

if(!$('#fb-root').length) { $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>'); }

return this.each(function() {

    $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass(settings.customClass);

    if(settings.loading) { $(this).html('<span class="facebook-loading">'+settings.loading+'</span>'); }

    var url = ($this.attr('data-account')) ? $this.attr('data-account') : settings.account;

    if(!/facebook.com/.test(url)) {
        url = "http://www.facebook.com/"+url;
    }
    var user = (/pages/.test(url)) ? url.split("/").pop() : url.match(/https?:\/\/(www\.)?facebook\.com\/(#!\/)?@?([^\/]*)/)[3];

    // here begins the trouble, i think
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/'+user
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function( data ) { 
            if(data.category) {
                // I guess $this is overwritten somehow?
                $this.html('<div class="facebookembed"><fb:like-box href="'+url+'"  width="'+settings.width+'" show_faces="'+settings.faces+'" stream="'+settings.stream+'" header="'+settings.header+'"></fb:like-box></div>');
            } else {
                $this.html('<div class="facebookuser"><a href="'+url+'" target="_blank"><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'+user+'/picture" /> Wordt vrienden met <strong>'+data.name+'</strong> op Facebook</a>');
            }
        }
        , error: function( data ) { $this.text('Deze gebruiker bestaat niet of niet meer...'); }
    } );

});
};
```

Html:

```
<div class="facebook-feed" data-account="skrillex"></div>
<div class="facebook-feed" data-account="noisia"></div>
etc..
<script type="text/javascript">$('.facebook-feed').facebookEmbed();</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without testing it looks like you are using `$this` in global scope. To keep it in local scope add `var` into declaration:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Comment: @Gijs, this is the correct answer.  Because you had declared $this as a global variable, by the time response came back and the success callback functions executed, the value of $this was already set to the last called value.  By using 'var', you can make $this variable local which will get captured through closure for each success callback function definition.

Setting the context for ajax call does nothing for your code.

Comment: ow snap i saw it wrong (i thought i had the var added) but the context did solve it as wel, it fixed it but wasn't the solution. I'm sorry and stand corrected!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `context` option?

```
$.ajax( {
    url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/'+user
    , context: $this
    , ...
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):
This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to $.ajax).

In your code you set the `$this` variable to a new object before the ajax call returns. Presumely all ajax calls return after you have set `$this` in the last `each` method.

Comment: @Gijs, I don't know why my comment was deleted but please leave it for anyone else who might stumble on to the same problem.  If you say setting the context solved your problem, then I am happy for you.
But, from logic point of view, it is not related to the problem you were having.  In the ajax call, 'this' is not used anywhere in the code and that's what context will alter.  The correct solution is the one Mike provided.  Thank you.

Comment: @Chi I don't know what you mean with your removed comment, i didn't remove it, i think it's still in the accepted answer. I first accepted this answer but later changed it to Mika's answer when i saw you pointing out my mistake.